# Openssl "verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate" on Mac

Tags: macos, openssl, command

I am not able to get rid of error "unable to get local issuer certificate" even after going through almost all suggestions on Stack Overflow on my MacBook.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -tls1 -showcerts -CApath /System/Library/OpenSSL
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
< Root and Intermediate Certificates >
```

I get same error with below command where I have copied the GeoTrust Root CA cert.

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -tls1 -CApath /usr/local/etc/openssl
```

This is failing at Depth 2. I tried below variation:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -tls1 -showcerts -CAfile ~/Certificates.pem
```

Here Certificates.pem contains all exported Root CA certificates from OSX's Keychain.

It is failing to validate *.google.com which is at Depth 2.
[image]

Any ideas how to get rid of that error? Any corner case due to use of WildCard certificates?

Comment: OpenSSL Version? Is Certificates.pem a PEM file, does it contain  (many instances of) the string `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`?

Comment: Version: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
Certificates.pem contains many such blocks all encapsulated with BEGIN and END header/footer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: OpenSSL.exe is obviously a developer tool, and thus on-topic here.

Comment: @Turbo - OpenSSL may be used by developers on occasion, but its hardly a developer tool. My bar is *so* low I take any code snippet and it passes unmolested. But because its not a development topic, there is no code in the question. There is no developer context here: *"Any ideas how to get rid of that error? Any corner case due to use of WildCard certificates?"*. Someone is looking for help running commands, and Stack Overflow is ***not*** chartered for it. There are better sites for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OpenSSL is really old, and may not [support SHA256](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility#1b). Unfortunately this hash method is used in the newer certificates - you need to update OpenSSL.

Comment: Sure will update the same, try again and post the output.

Comment: I am not getting any error on version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 on CentOS 6.6 and getting all intermediate certs as well. But it's giving "verify return:1", is that expected?